# Find Index of a string Vector using older compiler C++

Tags: c++, vector

I am looking to find the index of the vector I am using after the user has inputted the string.

the vector I am using is :

```
vector<string> names;
```

After several hours of researching this is what I've came up with, still doesn't work, I am using an old compiler DEV C++ making it impossible for me to use distance + find().

```
int find(vector<string>&v )
{
    string t;
    bool found=false;
    for(int i=0; i< v.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter the string to find " << endl;
        cin >> t;
        if(v[i]==t)
        {
            found=true;
            return i;
        }
    }
if(!found)
    {
        found=!true;
        return -1;
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you try? The standard library implementation that comes with Dev C++ still has [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) as far as I can remember.

Comment: Why are you asking for the string at *every* iteration?

Comment: And what `found=!true;` is supposed to do?

Comment: If the user wanting to find the index of more than element.

Comment: found=!true essentially return -1;

Comment: @fsfh60, you only return **one** index, why bother the user? If they want one string out of 1000, they'll have to retype it 1000 times in the worst case. Then they'll leave online reviews about how awful the UX in your software is.

Comment: `found=!true` do not return anything and does nothing at all in this statement, because variable `found` is no longer used anywhere

Comment: @StoryTeller , I understand.
Would you guys know how to find the index of such though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logic you are using is incorrect. You need to ask the user for the input first before looking in the vector.

The function can also be simplified a little bit.

```
int find(vector<string>&v )
{
   string t;

   // Gather the input from the user first
   cout << "Enter the string to find " << endl;
   cin >> t;

   // Now look for the string in the vector.
   for(int i=0; i< v.size(); i++)
   {
      if(v[i]==t)
      {
         return i;
      }
   }

   // If execution gets here, the string was not found.
   return -1;
}
```

---

A better design for the function is not to have the calls to `cin` in the function. Have the user gather the string they want to search for in the calling function.

```
int find(std::vector<std::string> const& v,
         std::string const& t )
{
   for(int i=0; i< v.size(); i++)
   {
      if(v[i]==t)
      {
         return i;
      }
   }

   // If execution gets here, the string was not found.
   return -1;
}
```

In `main`:

```
int main()
{
   // Construct v and flesh it out.
   std::vector<std::string> v;

   ...

   std::string t;

   // Gather the input from the user first
   cout << "Enter the string to find " << endl;
   cin >> t;

   int index = find(v, t);

   ...
}
```

Comment: This is very helpful , Although it didn't output the index? Any ideas what more I need to do ? I made the function and called it in the int main(). Cheers Thanks.

Comment: @fsfh60, the answer is in the question. output the index `cout << index`...

Comment: @fsfh60, what do you mean by that? Did you get no output, incorrect output?

Comment: @fsfh60, I would suggest creating a new post with a [mcve], the input, and the output.

Answer (score 3):

Look, if you don't have `std::find`, sure write your own. But at least make it somewhat reusable.

- Don't keep asking the user for input. Pass it as a function parameter.
- Don't hardwire `std::string` into it. Make it a template.

  ```
  template<typename T>
  int find(std::vector<T> const&v, T const& e)
  {
    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
      if(v[i] == t)
        return i;

    return -1;
  }
  ```

You can now use your `find` implementation on vectors of `string`, `int` or anything that implements `operator==` really.